# How to fix a ThreadAbortException in an Excel VSTO project because of a NativeWindow?

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel, winforms, vsto

In a VSTO project targeting Office 2007 and 2010 I am getting a ThreadAbortException after `ThisAddIn_Shutdown` has completed.  I believe this is being caused by my implementation of a NativeWindow and that I clean it up in the Shutdown.  I am using NativeWindow so that my VSTO addin can have HotKeys and I can detect which keys were pressed.

There is a [similar question here but I am not using it for a form so I cannot use this solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23519382/form-showiwin32window-method-in-excel-vsto-causing-threadabortexception-on-app)

In this [thread the problem is better explained.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2498af9b-2172-43cf-8616-1863f293ccb8/how-to-get-iwin32window-for-showshowdialog-in-excel?forum=vsto)

> You must release your subclass on the main Excel window prior to Shutdown.  The reason for this is that the loader calls shutdown in response to the main Excel window closing.  So if you have not called ReleaseHandle prior to Excel's main window closing, the WM_CLOSE will first get dispatched to the NativeWindow's managed WndProc.  This puts managed code on the stack below the loader shutdown code.  So the loader calls shutdown and unloads the AppDomain, but then the stack continues to unwind and it encounters managed code.  Since the AppDomain has been unloaded, an AppDomainUnloadedException is thrown, but since there is no handler available, Excel crashes.

But once again I cannot use the solution as I am not using it for a form.

So as far as I can tell the solution is to clean up the NativeWindow stuff before Excel is closing.

How can I do that?

The only thing I found / thought of would be something along the lines [of the solution to this Word issue.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d9f6417f-d809-4cc4-9b0e-6579af71e525/crash-when-closing-a-vsto-2010-word-document-from-a-user-control-in-the-task-pane-when-another?forum=vsto) which is to send a WM_CLOSE message. I could cancel an Application quit clean up my native window and close Excel myself.

But I am not sure Excel (2007 / 2010) exposes something to know when it is shutting down that is early enough to cancel.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    public MyNativeWindow MyNativeExcelWindow { get; private set; }

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var excelHwnd_IntPtr = new IntPtr(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Hwnd);
        MyNativeExcelWindow = new MyNativeWindow();
        MyNativeExcelWindow.AssignHandle(excelHwnd_IntPtr);
        ...
    } 
    ...
}

public class MyNativeWindow : NativeWindow
{
    private const int WM_CLOSE = 16;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_CLOSE) 
        {
            // Release handle for this native window before closing app...
            ReleaseHandle();

            // Then go on closing...
            PostMessage(m.HWnd, Convert.ToUInt32(m.Msg), m.WParam.ToInt32(), m.LParam.ToInt32());
        }
        else
        {
            // HERE YOU CAN PROCESS OTHER MESSAGES...

            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
}
```